# Change button_to text after click with coffeescript

Tags: jquery, coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

trying to do a pretty simple thing but all the information I can find online (for "beginners") seems to omit some core things I'm expected to know, because it doesn't even do so much as throw an error. Rails 5.2

I just want to change the text of my button on click.

I have a standard button_to

```
<%= button_to "Unsave", resource_path(id: resource.id), remote: true, method: :delete, class: "save_btn", id: "save_btn"%>
```

I have saved the following to "resources.coffee" in my javascripts folder

```
$ ->
  $(".save_btn").on "ajax:success", (e, data, status, xhr) ->
   $('.save_btn').text('Save')
```

In my application.html.erb layout I am loading my JS

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all',
                                          'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'resources', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
```

Rails threw me an error and instructed me to insert this into assets.rb, which I have done

```
Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( resources.js )
```

Nothing happens to the button when I click it. Can somebody please fill in the blanks for me? I have no javascript experience and I am pretty sure I am missing something to the equivalent of "Is it plugged in?".

Comment: This all looks good - two things to check initially: that the script is loading by adding `alert('Loaded')` after the line `$ ->`, and check the Rails logs to confirm your controller is definitely returning a successful response. Hope that helps get started!